# JQuery - add and focus next form field by pressing enter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add new input fields by pressing enter. Now, when I do press Enter, a new field is added, but the focus shifts directly to the Submit button, instead of to a newly added field. How can I prevent this?

Also, how can I add a sort of "prevention" so that a new field cannot be added, unless something has been written into the current one?

Here's how it currently works: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reeson46/h9bcas82/4/)

**EDIT**
I also figure it out how to prevent adding the next field, if the current one is empty: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reeson46/dr1g4xL9/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#items").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#items').append('<div><input id="sub" type="text" name="subtask">' +
        '<input type="button" value="delete" id="delete" /></div>');
      $(this).next().focus();
    }
  });


  $("body").on('click', "#delete", function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="items">
    <input id="sub" type="text" name="subtask">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742349/focus-on-next-tabindex-of-html-element-onenter-keypress-by-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [focus on next tabindex of HTML element onEnter keypress by JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742349/focus-on-next-tabindex-of-html-element-onenter-keypress-by-jquery)

Comment: By always inserting the same ID you produce invalid HTML `id="sub" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should give classes to your recurring elements,because when adding them you end up with multiple of the same id's,which are supposed to be unique.
2. Your `keypress` event,targets `#items` div and when you ask to give focus on the `next()` item,at the time of the event keypress the next item is the submit button.

3.You can also exclude an item from being focused,just give it the `tabindex` attribute and set a negative value,for example -1 (see snippet)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#items").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#items').append('<div><input class="sub" type="text" name="subtask">' + 
        '<input type="button" value="delete" class="delete" /></div>');
      $(".sub").last().focus();
    }
    
  });


  $("body").on('click', ".delete",function(e){
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="items">
    <input class="sub" type="text" name="subtask">
  </div>
  <input tabindex="-1" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I see. I assumed that "next()" would jump to the next input field, since the "next()" is being called after the filed is created. Now that you explained, I see what I did wrong. I was targeting the "#item", and the one after it is "submit", since the "next()" does not go inside inner elements, right? Cheers for the solution!