# How to check shift+tab is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input fields on my UI as in which one of them is `readonly` so after entering something in my first input field when I press enter it goes directly to 3rd one which is editable

What I am trying is when I am in 3rd Input field and there I press `shift+tab` I want to go back to first Input field which is editable, I have tried many things on google but not working

```js
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keycode == '13') {
    if (event.target.matches('[name=hsnCodeInput]')) {
      $("#mbqInput").focus();
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="hsnCodeInput">HSN Code</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hsnCodeInput" name="hsnCodeInput">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="searchCodeInput">Search Code</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchCodeInput" name="searchCodeInput" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="mbqInput">MBQ</label> <input type="text" min="0" class="form-control" id="mbqInput" name="mbqInput">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the key code for shift+tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044083/what-is-the-key-code-for-shifttab)

Comment: Try using `tabindex="-1"` on your readonly field. It should be removed from the tabbing cycle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture "shift+tab" keypress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421936/capture-shifttab-keypress-event)

Comment: But now the problem is different from duplicated quesyion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tabindex="-1"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) on `readonly` solves this problem

> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element should
>   be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard
>   navigation. It's mostly useful to create accessible widgets with
>   JavaScript.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="hsnCodeInput">HSN Code</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hsnCodeInput" name="hsnCodeInput">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="searchCodeInput">Search Code</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchCodeInput" name="searchCodeInput" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="mbqInput">MBQ</label> <input type="text" min="0" class="form-control" id="mbqInput" name="mbqInput">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

***Answer to prevent select readonly:***
 `tabindex="-1"` can prevent to select readonly textbox,

***How to check `tab` or `shift` + `tab` pressed***
and Tab feature is working fine to select next element, without any changes, and if we want to do some specific functions like, to click specific button or trigger specific function or plugin, then we have to manipulate the `tab` feature.

So for that I write following code, might help

**FIY**

When `tab` pressed key is `9`
When `Shift`+`tab` pressed key is `16`

Enjoy the code, 
Happy to help

```js
  document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
  var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keycode === 9) {
    // tab pressed
    alert('Tab pressed')

  }

  if (keycode === 16) {
      // tab + shift pressed

      alert('Tab + Shift pressed')
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="hsnCodeInput">HSN Code</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hsnCodeInput" name="hsnCodeInput">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="searchCodeInput">Search Code</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchCodeInput" name="searchCodeInput" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="mbqInput">MBQ</label> <input type="text" min="0" class="form-control" id="mbqInput" name="mbqInput">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey have you check it is not working for combination of keys like `alt+s` or `shift+tab`

Comment: Yes, because I didn't write code for `Alt` + `S`. I write only for `Tab` and `Tab + Shift` and its working fine

Comment: nop `tab+shift` is also not working anyway I found how to handle special key events